# How to find office web apps server in existing farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-web-apps, sharepoint-administration

Today one of the SharePoint farm was handed over to me but I was not able find the office web apps server.

So can anyone tell me how to find office web apps server in existing SharePoint farm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a couple of commands to get the details of the Office Online server.

```
(Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm).Machines
```

The above command will return details about the servers that are members of the Office Online Server farm. These details include the health status and roles held by each server.

```
Import-Module OfficeWebApps
Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm
```

The above command will return the details about the OfficeWebAppsFarm object.

Example something like below information you will get about OOS server:

[image: Get-webapps-powershell]

[Image source](https://danjmcintyre.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/webapps-powershell-error-1.jpg)

```
Get-OfficeWebAppsMachine
```

The **Get-OfficeWebAppsMachine** cmdlet returns details about the current server that is in an Office Online Server farm. These details include the roles and health status of the current server and the name of the master server for the farm.

```
Get-SPWOPIZone | Get-SPWOPIBinding
```

This example returns a list of bindings that were created on the current SharePoint farm where this cmdlet is run for the zone configured for the WOPI application.

For more details refer to the below MSDN articles:

- [Get-OfficeWebAppsMachine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/officewebapps/get-officewebappsmachine?view=officewebapps-ps)
- [Get-SPWOPIBinding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spwopibinding?view=sharepoint-ps)
- [Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/officewebapps/get-officewebappsfarm?view=officewebapps-ps)

**If you get the "The term 'Get-OfficeWebAppsMachine' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program." run the below command:**

```
$p=$Env:PSModulePath
$p+=";C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Web Apps\AdminModule"
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath",$p)
```

Source:

[Issues with OWA server 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/227650/issues-with-owa-server-2013)

Comment: Hi, I tried the above commands but I am getting the following errors. The term 'Get-OfficeWebAppsMachine' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

The term 'Get-SPWOPIBinding' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, functio
n, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a pa
th was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Try to run this command: the $p=$Env:PSModulePath
$p+=";C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Web Apps\AdminModule"
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath",$p)  ,refer this thread for more details: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/227650/issues-with-owa-server-2013

Comment: Folders are not there in this path C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Web Apps\AdminModule . I am actually checking this on sharepoint 2010 farm.

Comment: In 2010 the path could be different, check if you find any similar path there

Comment: Before the command try to include Import-Module OfficeWebApps

Comment: Everyone.  The questioner states they have no idea “which” server WAC is on.  All the OfficeWebApp cmdlets will fail unless on an actual WAC server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following command: [Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/officewebapps/get-officewebappsfarm)
, it should return an object containing details about the server(s) that are part of the Office Web Apps installation.

Comment: Hi, I tried the above command but I am getting the following error. The term 'Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, fun
ction, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.